# Get CSV File From URL & Convert to JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, request-promise, csvtojson

I need to get data from a csv file hosted on a url and convert it to json array. Till now I'm using this.

```
    import request from "request-promise";
    import encode from "nodejs-base64-encode";

    let url = 'https://example.com/filename.csv';

    function conversion(url) {
        return request.get(url, {encoding: null})
        .then( function (res) {
            //var base64File = encode.encode(res, 'base64');
            //how to convert the received data to json
        });
    }
```

I have tried converting to base64 first and then decoding the string but it just gives me string like below.

```
name,value,email
jason,23,email@email.com
jeremy,45,email@email.com
nigel,23,email@email.com
jason,23,email@email.com
```

I need it as a json array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include a package like [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson) to handle this conversion for you.

```js
/** csv file
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
*/
const csvFilePath='<path to csv file>'
const csv=require('csvtojson')
csv()
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.then((jsonObj)=>{
    console.log(jsonObj);
    /**
     * [
     *  {a:"1", b:"2", c:"3"},
     *  {a:"4", b:"5". c:"6"}
     * ]
     */ 
})

// Async / await usage
const jsonArray=await csv().fromFile(csvFilePath);
```

Comment: already tried that, it doesnt work. Throws this error: ***File does not exist. Check to make sure the file path to your csv is correct.\n at /dynamic-modules/third-party-npm/3e37bb12/WC_BEGIN/csvtojson/2.0.10/WC_END/csvtojson/src/Converter.ts:52:28\n at suppressedCallback (fs.js:213:5)\n at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:157:23)***

Comment: The url is correct, have checked it multiple times. I think it expects a local path which is not possible as this is a web hosted file

Comment: Have a look on their npm page and look for "Asynchronously process each line from csv url". There is an example of how to work with web hosted CSV files.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

You're halfway there.

You just need to:

1. split the string by end-of-line `\n`. You get an array of strings,
   each representing a line in your csv file.
2. split each line by `,`.

And in your case, don't forget to ignore the first line (the header).

Check this article out:

https://medium.com/@sanderdebr/converting-csv-to-a-2d-array-of-objects-94d43c56b12d

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by `\r\n` to get an array of strings. Use the `.map` in array to make it an array of objects.

Here is an example:

```
var newArray = decodedString.split('\r\n').slice(1)map(row => {
    var temp = row.split(',')
    return {
             name: temp[0],
             value: temp[1],
             email: temp[2]
        }
})
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That's a horribly over-simplified approach to parsing CSV that doesn't take into account any of the subtleties of the format (like quoted fields and escaped characters)

Answer (score 0):

Include a package called  **csvtojson**

```
const request=require('request')
const csv=require('csvtojson')
 
csv()
.fromStream(request.get('http://mywebsite.com/mycsvfile.csv'))
.subscribe((json)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        // long operation for each json e.g. transform / write into database.
    })
},onError,onComplete);
```

With Async and Await

```
async function ConvertCSVtoJSON{
const jsonArray = await csv().fromStream(request.get('http://mywebsite.com/mycsvfile.csv'));
        console.log(jsonArray);
}
```